# NHibernate creates query with incorrect parameter list

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm getting a `GenericADOException` with the message:

> `could not execute query`

related to the following query, being generated by NHibernate:

```
select aggregated0_.Id as col_0_0_
     , aggregated0_.Name as col_1_0_
     , aggregated0_.Event as col_2_0_
     , cast(count(distinct aggregated0_.Code) as INT) as col_3_0_ 
from Events aggregated0_ 
where 
    aggregated0_.RelatedId=@p0 
    and aggregated0_.S_Id=@p1
    and aggregated0_.HappenedAt >=@p2
group by 
    aggregated0_.Id
    , aggregated0_.Name
    , aggregated0_.Event    

Name:p1 - Value:97c58b27-460d-4fae-8185-b215e2d11882  
Name:p2 - Value:4d3b7583-4b46-46e2-8bcd-169b26fd3541  
Name:p3 - Value:7/25/2017 11:00:00 PM
```

As you can see, the parameter list is, incorrectly, using p1, p2 and p3. However, the query needs p0, p1 and p2.

Why is NH creating an incorrect parameter list?

Mapping:

```
public AggregatedEventMap()
{
    SchemaAction.None();

    Table("Events");
    ReadOnly();
    Not.LazyLoad();

    Id(e => e.E_Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

    Map(m => m.RelatedId);
    Map(m => m.S_Id);
    Map(m => m.P_Id);
    Map(m => m.Id);
    Map(m => m.Name);
    Map(m => m.Code);
    Map(m => m.Event);

    Map(m => m.EventTime).CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
    Map(m => m.HappenedAt).CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
}
```

Query is built as follows:

```
var query = 
    Session
        .Query<AggregatedEvent>()
        .Where(e => e.RelatedId == parameters.RelatedId);

        if (parameters.S_Id.HasValue)
        {
            query = 
                query.Where(e => e.S_Id == parameters.S_Id.Value);
        }

        if (parameters.P_Id.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.P_Id == parameters.P_Id.Value);
        }

        if (parameters.Id.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.Id == parameters.Id.Value);
        }

        if (parameters.FromDate.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.HappenedAt >= parameters.FromDate.Value);
        }

        if (parameters.ToDate.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.HappenedAt < parameters.ToDate.Value);
        }

var results =
    query
        .GroupBy(e => new { e.Id, e.Name, e.Event })
        .Select(
            g => 
                new AggregatedEventResult
                {
                    Id = g.Key.Id,
                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                    Event = g.Key.Event,
                    Count = g.Select(e => e.Code).Distinct().Count()
                })
                .ToList();
```

Furthermore, this doesn't happen consistently and only happens in one runtime environment. It only happens when a certain combination of parameters is used:

`RelatedId`, `S_ID` and when `HappenedAt` is queried for events on, or after a given date.

Comment: Could you show how do you query it from c# code ?

Comment: Great edit! Although I can't see any problems with your setup. This smells like a nasty NHibernate bug. Did you try experiencing with different driver or different dialect at the SessionFactory setup?

Comment: Not yet. Good ideas though, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the scenarios where you've seen this happen? You mention 1 runtime environment. Do you mean that running in 2 different servers against the same database, one server trips up but the other works for the same combination? Or is it against database A it trips up, but Database B it doesn't?  In cases where it fails, it will fail on S_id + HappenedAt, but works with different parameters? (what about additional parameters, SID + HappenedAt + another)

Comment: It only happens in our production environment. Not our staging environment, despite the environments being identical. It only seems to happen when you use the combination of parameters I mention in the question. I initially thought that the `SessionFactory` had somehow built an incorrect query and cached it. So I reset the application, but this had no effect.

Comment: Does it happen when you create the query using ICriteria instead of QueryOver ?

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I haven't tested this as I cannot replicate the problem in a development environment. It's a good avenue to explore though. Are you thinking it's a bug in the LINQ provider?

Comment: That would be my first thought, that's why I asked.  Since it is not possible to reproduce in multiple environments, it might be related with other software or configuration settings as well.

Comment: I too have ran into this issue and was able to recreate it with 2 servers (1 working, 1 failing) - I think an IIS recycle fixes the issue, but not sure why it happened in the first place yet.